# Problema con el sistema numérico de cada región

Tags: c#, csv, unity3d, unity, unity2d

¡Buenas a todos!

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Unity donde uso archivos .CSV para recoger los datos a utilizar en el proyecto. Dato importante es que estoy desarrollando el proyecto con la región del sistema operativo (SO) en Español (España, internacional).

Este .CSV lo uso para listar una serie de acciones que quiero que realicen mis personajes dentro del juego, como por ejemplo moverse del punto donde están a un punto A o que esperen es la posición actual durante X seg. En el .CSV guardo los datos como string, pero al introducirlos en el proyecto los necesito como float:

- **MOVE: float Velocity, float Position.x, float Position.y, float Position.z**
- **WAIT: float Time**

Cualquiera de estas acciones está enlazada a un objecto que recibe esta acción y se ejecuta perfectamente.

El problema surgió cuando mandé una build a Steam para que me validasen el proyecto y me notificaron que no habían podido avanzar porque los personajes no se movían (el juego funcionaba, pero no se movía nada).

Después de muchas pruebas, encontré el problema. Resulta que si el SO donde se ejecuta la build del proyecto, está en una región diferente a Español (España, internacional), como por ejemplo en English (United Kingdom), el juego se ejecuta pero no se mueve nada en los tiempos que originalmente programé.

Este problema viene dado porque en cada región tienen un sistema decimal diferente, por ejemplo, en España se usa los puntos para indicar las unidades y las comas para indicar los decimales ("1.234,24") y en Inglaterra es al contrario ("1,234.24"), por lo que si declaro que mi personaje se espere (WAIT) durante "0,2" segundos (España), en un SO con región English (United Kingdom), serán "20" segundos, por que interpreta las comas como separador de unidades. Lo mismo ocurre con las acciones MOVE.

Para no tener que cambiar la región de mi SO, cambié las comas por puntos en el .CSV para trasladar el problema a mi región y hacer las pruebas necesarias. Con lo que pude probar el directo que si ponía "3.00" (que serían 3 segundos) mi SO lo interpreta como 3 minutos.

Mi pregunta es: **¿de qué forma podría solucionar esto para que funcione en los tiempos que quiero independientemente de la región del SO en el que se ejecute?**

Intenté hacer un parse manual de string a float cambiando el punto por la coma, pero me di cuenta que aunque solucionase el error en mi región, se iba a trasladar a otra región.

**¿Hay alguna forma de configurar que el proyecto siempre use un sistema numérico concreto independiente del SO?** Es decir, que interprete la coma como decimal y que la use con ese propósito sea la región que sea.

Probé con `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`, pero no conseguí nada (o no terminé de entenderlo).

**¿Hay alguna forma de crear un parse manual que funcione en cualquier región?**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Donde esta el codigo que realizaste para cambiar la cultura? Resumi la pregunta ya que no es necesaria toda la explicacion para solo querer cambiar la cultura.

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone gracias por resumir la pregunta, pero no me intentaba centrar en el cambio de cultura. Quería dejar la preguntar abierta para otras posibles soluciones e indicar qué había probado, por si a otro usuario se le ocurría otra nueva forma. Al final, el problema estaba no entender correctamente el funcionamiento de CultureInfo. He dejado la solución a la pregunta más abajo. Muchas gracias por mostrar interés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a mi pregunta era bastante sencilla, simplemente no terminaba de entender el uso lógico de `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`, ya que la solución estaba ahí.

Lo que necesitaba era poder convertir un string en un float y que tuviera un sistema numérico que todos los SO pudieran entender. Para ello, lo que intentaba era convertir la entrada de datos en un sistema en concreto, por ejemplo, un string "1,25" en un float y que en el parse fuera el encargado de cambiar la coma por el punto usando la codificación `"en-US"`.

Como puede verse, mi lógica fallaba ya que `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` no hace este cambio. Su función es simple, se usa cuando se quiere forzar al proyecto a que entienda la entrada de datos en una codificación especifica. Si se está usando un sistema "en-US" no podía pasar un .CSV con comas para los decimales (1.234,56) porque no lo iba a entender, tenía que pasar las comas cambiadas por puntos directamente en el .CSV.

Aun así, entendí que utilizar .CSV para almacenar datos numéricos no es la mejor opción y en futuros proyectos buscaré otros sistemas más efectivos.

Dejo esta explicación como nota informativa por si alguien tropieza con este error, que lo pueda entender y solucionar fácilmente.

El proceso que llevé a cabo es usar un parse con una cultura por defecto:

```
using System.Globalization;

public class ExampleCultureInfo : MonoBehaviour {

    CultureInfo culture;
    float time;
    string data = "3.25";

    void Start(){ 
        culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }

    void Update(){
        // En caso de procesar el dato sin intervención del usuario
        time = float.Parse(data, culture);
    }
}
```

El `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` sirve para formatear la cultura del programa en la cultura más usada, en este caso, usar `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` seria lo mismo que usar `CultureInfo("en-US", false)` por lo que todo dato que intentemos convertir deberá entrar en el sistema numérico de `"en-US"`, es decir, con comas para separar las unidades y puntos para los decimales (1,234.56).

Si, como yo, se está usando un .CSV para guardar los datos, simplemente se tendrá que acceder a las opciones de excel y cambiar los "separadores del sistema":

**Archivo > Opciones > Avanzadas > Usar separadores del sistema**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así, cuando guardes en .CSV las unidades/miles estarán en un formato que tu proyecto pueda entender en cualquier SO en el que se ejecute.

Tengo que dar las gracias al usuario de Stackoverflow en inglés, [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61612569/6129931), por haberme dado las herramientas para solucionar el problema. Si no os queda claro por mi explicación, podéis ir a la contestación que me dio y resolverlo por vosotros mismos.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Claro, esa es una forma, pero se la pasas cada vez que hagas un Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Podes setear la cultura de esta manera y no tener que hacerlo en cada parse, porque lo deja en el nivel del proceso al cambio.

```
//Son dos formas de hacerlo, en mi experiencia siempre uso la primera.

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: Hola Ramiro, he visto ese uso varias veces pero no he llegado a entenderlo. ¿Podrías detallarlo o incluir algún enlace donde se explique? Me ayudarías a entender mejor este concepto. Gracias.